# No realiza consulta php

Tags: php, mysql

Hola alguien me puede ayudar con esta función,
realiza la conexión, pero la consulta no se ejecuta.

Aquí llamo a la función

ACTUALIZACION:
Ya pude avanzar un poco, agregué una variable en la conexión para retornarla y asi logre pasar de el if, pero ahora me esta enviando el error:

Fatal error: Uncaught mysqli_sql_exception: No database selected

en esta linea:

```
$result = $this->oConBD->query($query);
```

aunque hasta donde entendi si estoy seleccionando la base aqui:

```
$resultado=$this->oConBD = new mysqli($this->ip, $this->UsuarioBD, $this->PasBD, $this->nombreBD);
```

Alguna idea de cual es el error que estoy cometiendo?

```
<?php
include "./mysql.php";

$oMysql=new mysql();
$oMysql->execQueryOB($oMysql->sqlInsert);
?>
```

Aqui mi codigo donde viene la funcion:

```
<?php
/** 
 * Pruebas mysql --- php
 * 
 * 
*/
include '../config.php';

class mysql{
    private $oConBD=null;
    public $sqlInsert ="INSERT into datos_prueba (id,nombre,contraseña,correo)values ('1','David','1234','******a@c****sa.com.mx');";

    public function _contruct(){
        global $UsuarioBD, $PasBD, $ip, $nombreBD;

        $this->UsuarioBD=$UsuarioBD;
        $this->PasBD=$PasBD;
        $this->ip=$ip;
        $this->nombreBD=$nombreBD;
    }

    public function conBDOB()
{
    $resultado=false;
    $resultado=$this->oConBD = new mysqli($this->ip, $this->UsuarioBD, $this->PasBD, $this->nombreBD);
    if ($this->oConBD->connect_error) {
        echo "Error al conectar: " . mysqli_connect_error() . "\n";
        return false;
    } else {
        echo "Conexion exitosa" . "\n";
    }
    
   return $resultado;
}


    public function execQueryOB($query)
    {
        $result = false;
        if ($this->conBDOB() && $query != '') {
            // ACA
            $result = $this->oConBD->query($query);
            if ($result !== false) {
                echo "Consulta ejecutada \n";
            } else {
                echo "Fallo la consulta por: " . $this->oConBD->error . "\n";
            }
        
        }else{
            echo "Algo fallo";
        }
        return $result;
    }
}
?>
```

Cualquier ayuda se los agradecería, soy nuevo en php

Comment: Saludos. Revisa el error que se genera; en tu código que muestras la instrucción INSERT no tiene (por decir un dato) **David** que seguro es un texto no está entre comillas como corresponde. Verifica que cada dato lo estás pasando como corresponde.

Comment: Hola gracias por responder, en realidad no me manda ningun error  me responde conexion exitosa, a lo que veo esta incumpliendose esta condicion  if($this->conBDOB() && $query != '')   de echo agregue un else en ese if y es ahi donde se va pero no se porque, es como si $query estuviera vacio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya quedo resuelto  muchas gracias a Marcos por su ayuda, me ayudo a comprender mejor la logica de php lo dejo aqui por si alguien tiene algun problema parecido.

```
<?php
/** 
 * Pruebas mysql --- php
 * 
 * 
*/
include '../config.php';

class mysql{
    private $oConBD=null;
    public $sqlInsert ="INSERT into pruebas.datos_prueba (id,nombre,contraseña,correo) values ('3','nuevoUsr','1234','nuevo@*****a.com.mx')";
    public $select ="SELECT * FROM pruebas.datos_prueba";
    public $update=" UPDATE pruebas.datos_prueba SET nombre=?, correo=? WHERE id=2";


    public function _contruct(){
        global $UsuarioBD, $PasBD, $ip, $nombreBD;

        $this->UsuarioBD=$UsuarioBD;
        $this->PasBD=$PasBD;
        $this->ip=$ip;
        $this->nombreBD=$nombreBD;
    }

    public function conBDOB()
    {
        $resultado=false;
        $resultado=$this->oConBD = new mysqli($this->ip, $this->UsuarioBD, $this->PasBD, $this->nombreBD);
        if ($this->oConBD->connect_error) {
            echo "Error al conectar: " . mysqli_connect_error() . "\n";
            return false;
        } else {
            echo "Conexion exitosa" . "\n";
        }
        
       return $resultado;
    }

    public function execQueryOB($query)
    {
        $result = false;
        
        if ($this->conBDOB() && $query != '') {
            $result = $this->oConBD->query($query);
            if ($result !== false) {
                echo "Consulta ejecutada \n";
            } else {
                echo "Fallo la consulta por: " . $this->oConBD->error . "\n";
            }
            $this->oConDB->close();
        }else{
            echo "Algo fallo" ;
        }
        return $result;
    }
```

El primer error era que la función conBDOB no regresaba esto en el if lo tomaba como un false por eso brincaba al else, lo solucione retornando en una variable el resultado de la conexión

El segundo error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught mysqli_sql_exception: No database selected
```

este se soluciono agregando el nombre de la base de datos en la consulta (aunque no entendi muy bien porque lanzaba este error ya que en mi conexion si especifico la base de datos , quedo asi la consulta:

```
public $sqlInsert ="INSERT into pruebas.datos_prueba (id,nombre,contraseña,correo) values ('3','nuevoUsr','1234','nuevo@*****a.com.mx')";
```

Comment: Hola David, el segundo error debería solucionarse indicando `$nombreBD = 'pruebas';`

Comment: Hola si, así lo tengo. Pero esta en mi archivo config.php está mal ahí?

Answer (score 1):

El principal error es que no estas guardando, ni llamando, correctamente la referencia a la conexión (*lo que sería `$oConBD`*).

Por ejemplo, en lugar de hacer:

```
$oConBD=new mysqli(...
```

Lo correcto sería hacerlo así:

```
$this->oConBD=new mysqli(...
```

Además de eso tenes 3 errores más:

1. El hacer `if ($oConBD->query($query) === true) {` esta mal, ya que [`query`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php) no siempre devuelve `true`, por lo conviene evaluar que sea `!== false`.
2. No estas considerando el caso donde `query` devuelva un [`result`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli-result.php).
3. Para obtener el error, no es correcto hacer `$this->oConBD . error`. Lo correcto sería `$this->oConBD->error`

El código completo sería así:

```php
<?php

/** 
 * Pruebas mysql --- php
 * 
 * 
 */
include '../config.php';

class mysql
{
    private $oConBD = null;
    public $sqlInsert = "INSERT into datos_prueba (id,nombre,contraseña,correo)values (1,David,1234,****ada@****sa.com.mx)";

    public function _contruct()
    {
        global $UsuarioBD, $PasBD, $ip, $nombreBD;

        $this->UsuarioBD = $UsuarioBD;
        $this->PasBD = $PasBD;
        $this->ip = $ip;
        $this->nombreBD = $nombreBD;
    }

    public function conBDOB()
    {
        // ACA
        $this->oConBD = new mysqli($this->ip, $this->UsuarioBD, $this->PasBD, $this->nombreBD);
        // ACA
        if ($this->oConBD->connect_error) {
            echo "Error al conectar: " . mysqli_connect_error() . "\n";
            return false;
        } else {
            echo "Conexion exitosa";
        }
    }

    public function execQueryOB($query)
    {
        $result = false;
        if ($this->conBDOB() && $query != '') {
            // ACA
            $result = $this->oConBD->query($query);
            if ($result !== false) {
                echo "Consulta ejecutada \n";
            } else {
                echo "Fallo la consulta por: " . $this->oConBD->error . "\n";
            }
            $this->oConDB->close();
        }
        return $result;
    }
}
```

PD: Personalmente creo que no es una buena idea cerrar la conexíon cada vez que ejecutas una consulta. Deberías considerar cambiar esto.

Comment: Muchas gracias por la ayuda, ya realice los ajustes que me comentas, pero sigue sin ejecutarse la consulta .  Agregue un else para if ($this->conBDOB() && $query != '') {}else{ echo "algo fallo";} y lo que obtengo en pantalla es conexion exitosa algo fallo